# Tomcat: maxConnections, maxThreads, acceptCount settings and large http requests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, tomcat

I'm configuring Tomcat so it can process large http requests (e.g 100 mb each) and perform "back pressure" to slow down the consumer, so we won't fail on Out Of Memory.

Desired behavior:

- Tomcat processes large messages in a configured number of threads
- If all threads are occupied, Tomcat accepts the connections, but is not receiving the large data over the network and holding the connections until threads are available.

My guess is that configuration should be like this. Is it true?

```
maxThreads: 10 # the number calculated from available heap and average message size
maxConnections: 100 # it's ok to have 100 connections "on hold"
acceptCount: 10 # start dropping new connections once the queue is > 10
connectionTimeout: 600000 # it's ok to wait for 10 min
```

My biggest question is the following:
When Tomcat accepts the connection for large POST request, does it receives the data right away, or it will happen only when threads become available?